# multi item carousel bootstrap in wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I want to add a second carousel in my index page in wordpress which have to be multi items. the problem is that carousel controls overlap with my first carousel even due they have different Id.
here is the code :

```
<section class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="postsCarousel" style="margin-top:20px;">
   <div class="container carousel-inner" >
      <div class="item row  <?php echo ($count == 0) ? 'active' : ''; ?>"style="height:250px; background-color:transparent">
         <?php $slider = get_posts(array("category_name"=>"slider2", 'posts_per_page' => 6)); ?>
         <?php $count = 0; ?>
         <?php foreach($slider as $slide): ?>
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: auto; margin:20px">
               <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail();?>/..." alt="Card image cap">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                  <p class="card-text"><?php the_content(""); ?></p>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary " style="margin-bottom:6px;"> ادامه</a>
                  <div class="card-footer">
                     <small class="text-muted"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></small>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <?php $count++; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#postsCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="background-color:gray;border-radius:10px">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#postsCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next" style="background-color:gray;border-radius:10px">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
</section>
```

Comment: Do you have a dev link with the working code?

Comment: no, i'm sorry don't have it

Comment: I would suggest to use [owl carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html), it has many options to manage the slides.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your slider controls have position: absolute; css property,

try to apply position: relative; for the carousel parent

for example,

```
#postsCarousel{position:relative;}
```

so that position: absolute, will apply only for that first carousel controls.